# Regarding AWS device farm

Tags: aws

I am using Appium + TestNG scripts to run the AWS device farm. I understood how to work on the AWS.
But now i have some questions.

1. Where the Device farm is located and How to see the setting of locations.
2. Does they support calling functions, Camera, Videos and particularly ear phone jack to track down the FM app and its frequency.

Comment: Please do some research before asking questions. The AWS device farm documentation answers most if not all your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Most of your questions are answered in t[he AWS device farm FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/faq/):

> Q: My app makes use of **location** services. Can I specify the physical
>   location of the device?
>
> Yes, you can supply latitude and longitude coordinates that will be
>   used to **override** a device’s GPS.
>
> Q: Can I make phone calls or send SMS from the devices?
>
> No, devices do not have carrier connections and cannot make phone
>   calls or send SMS messages.
>
> Q: Can I use the device camera?
>
> Yes, you can use the device cameras, both front- and rear-facing. Due
>   to the way the devices are mounted, images and videos may look dark
>   and blurry.

Seems you can contact the AWS device farm support at [aws-devicefarm-support@amazon.com](http://mailto:aws-devicefarm-support@amazon.com) for your other questions. I except the answer will be currently not supported.

Comment: Hi Niels, I will do research before asking. But i have a doubt, I don't see any answers related to this. How to see default app of the Devices in AWS. I want track the FM frequencies. My sample app will take notification access to track down. Is frequency tracking is allowed or not in the Device farm.

Comment: So email support.

Comment: I sent an email to support team on 02/01/2017. No reply from them.

Comment: I think your expectations of Support responding surrounding the holidays are a bit high. I would give them wait a week to catch up, lol :)